# calculate elapsed time based on condition using if () function

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, custom-function

I'm trying to calculate the elapsed time based on a certain condition. In the dataset, aDUR to present time elapsed, TSFD represent time in hour. I only need to calculate aDUR when FLAG1 =1, which should be the TSFD of [i+1] record subtract the TSFD of [i] record. When FLAG1 = 0, all records aDUR are assigned with 1.

Here is sample of my dataset.

```
head(df1_2)
  C        ID DV    DATE      TIME   TSFD  TSLD  DOSE   MDV  EVID  RATE DUR      WT   AGE HEIGHT BMI         SEX    AMT    FLAG1
  <lgl> <int> <fct> <fct>     <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>  <fct>       <fct>  <fct>  <dbl>
1 NA    11003 .     3/14/2007 22:00     0     0    75     1     1  246. .      54.7  44.6 73     15.89851181 Female 245.97     0
2 NA    11003 .     3/14/2007 23:00     1     0    75     1     1  246. .      54.7  44.6 73     15.89851181 Female 245.97     1
3 NA    11003 .     3/15/2007 1:00      3     0    75     1     1  246. .      54.7  44.6 73     15.89851181 Female 245.97     0
4 NA    11003 .     3/15/2007 2:00      4     0    75     1     1  246. .      54.7  44.6 73     15.89851181 Female 245.97     0
5 NA    11003 .     3/15/2007 3:00      5     0    75     1     1  246. .      54.7  44.6 73     15.89851181 Female 245.97     0
6 NA    11003 .     3/15/2007 4:00      6     0    75     1     1  246. .      54.7  44.6 73     15.89851181 Female 245.97     1
```

I'm a newbie in R. Here is what I could think of, but it doesn't work. Can someone point out where I did wrong? I also tried ifelse, but I don't know how to calculate the elapsed time within ifelse function.

```
f2 <-function(fc){
  TSFD <- fc$TSFD
  FLAG1 <- fc$FLAG1
  aDUR <- rep(1,length(FLAG1))
  for (i in 1:length(FLAG1))
   if(FLAG1 == 1) {aDUR[i] <- TSFD[i+1]-TSFD[i]}
  fc$aDUR <- aDUR
  return(fc)
}
```

Also, I have multiple subjects in the dataset. How could I apply this function based on group of ID? 
I tried `df2 <- df1_2%>%group_by(ID)%>%f2(.)`. It doesnt work.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need:

```
df <- df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(aDUR = c(0, diff(TSFD)))
```